# Find the dimension of a subspace by find a basis for the null space.

Tags: linear-algebra

Below is the question and my proposed answer. It seems like it is a trick question, but maybe my answer is good enough or maybe I am wrong. Any help would be great.

2) Show that the dimension of the set $\lbrace (x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | 2x - 3y + z = 0 \rbrace$ is two by exhibiting a basis for the null space.

The subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ of concern is the image of the linear tranform $F: \mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}^3$

\begin{bmatrix}
       \frac{3}{2} & \frac{1}{2} \\[0.3em]
       1 & 0                                \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}

To find this matrix we solve the equation for $x$ to get $2x = 3y - z$ and we let $y = s$ and $z = t$ and then write out the matrix. The null space is equal to the kernel of $F$ which is the $\overrightarrow{0}$ vector since row reduced echelon form gives us

\begin{bmatrix}
       1 & 0 \\[0.3em]
       0 & 1 \\[0.3em]
       0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

The "rank-nullity" theorem says that if A is an $mxn$ matrix, then rank(A) + null(A) = n. Here the nullity is $0$ so the rank is 2 and we know that the dimension of the basis for a linear transform is equal to the rank of the matrix. So there really isn't a basis for the subspace.

Comment: The question says "by exhibiting a basis for the null space". The null space of what? I worry that it's asking you to consider that set,z not as the image of some matrix (as you've done), but as the null space of the matrix $[2\; {-3}\; 1]$. (Also note that you dropped a negative sign in the second column of your first matrix.)

Comment: (Also note that you dropped a negative sign in the second column of your first matrix.) Ah, yes. Thanks for the correction. 

I am confused about this question because I know that the dimension of the subspace is 2. I can exhibit a dimension for that subspace easily enough and the image of the matrix above is the set of vectors that solves the equation. But the dimension of the null space of [2 -3 1] is 2. How does that tell me that dimension of the set is 2?

Comment: Isn't the set in question precisely the null space of $[2\;{-3}\;1]$?

Comment: Ah! I see where I am pulling my hair out. There are two ways to parse the question. One way is to assume the question is asking for a basis of the matrix [2 -3 1] (as Greg says) and the other is to assume the question is asking for a basis of the null space of the given space (which is already a null space.) That happens to be the column space of the transformation. The other interpretation is the one answered above. Ambiguity does not belong in math questions!!!!

Thanks Greg.